# Is sending an email to username@facebook.com an allowed means of contact?

Tags: facebook, email, instant-messaging

I've noticed that I can send email to `username@facebook.com` and it will get delivered to a user's Facebook inbox. Is this allowed to be done programmatically (eg send via SendGrid to re-engage users)?

Does anyone have any experience doing this? If it's allowed is there anything to watch out for or be aware of?

Comment: This is explicitly against Facebook's policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ - IV.5

Comment: Good catch Igy, had not seen that Policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this programatically, but Facebook is smart about it. If you get an email from someone Facebook doesn't know or you aren't friends with, then it will go to the `Messages->Other` section. If it's an email that maps to a Facebook profile that is your friend, it will show up in your inbox.

Comment: A good thought but that doesn't appear to be the case. I sent to a test account via an anonymous mailer page I found online and it looks like it went through ( http://www.anonymailer.net/ )

Comment: It's easy to catch that with domain keys; facebook might not be doing that yet.